# HTTP Requests Query: Can i send a video over a HTTP request? And Send back json data and images?

Tags: android, http, request, http-post, httpresponse

So I want to build an android application, that users can take videos on, then send them to a web server to perform analysis on the video, send back metrics in JSON and also send back several images from the video. Is this possible? Is it a good/bad idea? If this is a dumb approach or this will be a very slow approach, any better strategies are welcome. Cheers!

Comment: since video is a file, you can send files. What the server will send back is decided by the server and it's code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can send video file to web-server and get response via JSON with images.

For sending video you can HTTP client retrofit which is very handy. You must use **@Multipart** in your API calling. Here is an example.

```
@POST("/your_url/")
Call<ResultObject> uploadVideoToServer(@Part MultipartBody.Part video);
```

You can call it like:

```
File videoFile = new File(pathToVideoFile);
RequestBody videoBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("video/*"), videoFile);
MultipartBody.Part vFile = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("video", videoFile.getName(), videoBody);
```

Your need a dedicated server (aws or digital ocean droplet) and well formed web apps in server (algorithm) to extract picture from your video for better user experience. Overall your idea is good & it's possible.